# If I'm using Next.js for frontend should I also use it for building rest API or do that in Nest.js instead?

Tags: next.js, nestjs

(Disclaimer: I'm very new to Next.js but I have already used Nest.js, and know how powerful it can be.)

In other words, is there a benefit for using Next.js for building rest API instead of a separate backend server?

I know you might say it really depends, so here are some requirements I know I'll have: SSR in Next.js, then also DB calls, external API calls, Authentication with different providers and own authentication, automated emails. Perhaps scheduled calculations with write to DBs.
I know also that if I wanted to use serverless hosting it also becomes a different situation.

Comment: Hi, You can build your REST apis within the NextJS project. Just create api files inside /api dir & request wherever you want.

Comment: Hi, I know I can, my question wasn't whether I can or not.